# How to save/load a dict of sparse list efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, pickle

I have a dict with like a million keys and each value is a 10000-dim sparse list, e.g.,

```
dic = {'a': [0] * 10000, 'b': [0] * 1234 + [1, 2] + [0] * 8764, ...}
```

Dumping the object via pickle is not quite efficient as it takes a ton of disk spaces. Is there a way/package that I could save/load this kind of object efficiently?

Comment: If your data is sparse you should consider using data structures meant for sparse data, scipy has support for sparse matrices that you can look into https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

This way the data you're pickling is only the actual data you care about

Comment: Those lists are neither multidimensional nor sparse. Lists are by definition one-dimensional, and you are explicitly storing some integer in each element of the list; 0 just indicates the lack of an otherwise more interesting value. A sparse list would be more like a `dict` with non-negative integer keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a sparse matrix using Scipy library as illustrated [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html). This function allows for compression as well, however, you need to represent your data in one of its supported formats.

You may also benefit by using Pandas data frames to store a sparse matrix ([more info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html)).

Comment: Then I would have to save my keys and values separately?

Comment: @Mr.cysl I believe so. You may also create a mapping for your keys and save them as the first row of your matrix, but it will not be that efficient when you save the matrix to disk as it won't be a sparse matrix. Saving them separately would be better. Your second option is to use Pandas dataframe and save them using Pandas supported formats: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the list objects with [scipy sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) (with csr matrix, for example).